# Sending messages to my localhost Jetty server

Tags: java, jetty

Using org.mortbay.jetty.Server;

I initialized my Jetty server to port 8080 (in the xml   ).

```
server = (Server) applicationContext.getBean("JettyServer");
```

I am sending HTTP messages (GET,PUT,HEAD) to my server on address: http://localhost:8080.

But instead of handling the requests like i defind with handlrs the server returns 404 "Server out-bound response".

What am i doin wrong?
Thanks.

Comment: Forget to mention that i use Jersey for handling the HTTP requests

Answer (score 2):

Have you attached a handler to handle the requests ? See this as demonstrated at http://wiki.eclipse.org/Jetty/Tutorial/Embedding_Jetty - **HelloHandler**

you will also need to set a contextHandler - See **Setting Contexts** section in above link and you will need to hit that URL while querying it.